# c# virtual keyboard p/ invoke shift wont "release" key

Tags: c#, pinvoke, shift, virtual-keyboard

## My current code is:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)] 
static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, int dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);  

public const int KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 0x0001; //Key down flag 
public const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x0002; //Key up flag 
public const int VK_RMENU = 0xA5;

keybd_event(VK_SHIFT, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);
keybd_event(VK_Q, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);
keybd_event(VK_Q, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
keybd_event(VK_SHIFT, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
```

I get the capital Q as needed, but the problem is, the "Shift" sticks.

All letter after that are all capital. the only way to get lowercase is to change to caps lock. How can i solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where are all of these people getting the idea to write new code using the `keybd_event` function? The preferred way of doing this for some time now has been to use the [`SendInput` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310.aspx).

Comment: Also, who told you that `KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY` was the "key down flag"? That's not what [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646304.aspx) says...

Comment: Thank you. BTW i had to use the keybd_event for some unusual webpage coding in Korean. It forces the Korean language input until the right alt key is pressed. it forced me to use keybd_event to simulate that keypress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe Cody Gray gave you the resolution for your issue. Just replace your P/Invoke calls with:

```
keybd_event(VK_SHIFT, 0, 0, 0);
keybd_event(VK_Q, 0, 0, 0);
keybd_event(VK_Q, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
keybd_event(VK_SHIFT, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
```

Comment: I did figure it out from Cody Gray's comment. Thank you though